# Angular: Display nothing incase *ngIf fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two arrays `fetchedData` and `cardCheckArray`. I am using nested loop and displaying the data of the `fetchedData` if some certain element in the `fetchedData` equals the `cardCheckArray`. It's kind of displaying subitems of an array but by using two different arrays. I am getting an issue here. Incase, if the element of the first array doesn't match with the second array, the Angular prints nothing but still occupies an empty line for each iteration when the condition fails. This is putting a lot of space under each card header. I want to somehow don't print empty whitespace if `*ngIf` fails. I have tried using `ng-template` but still getting the same issue.

Here's my code:

> HTML

```
<div *ngIf = "containsData">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div style = "width: 70%; margin: auto;" *ngFor = "let data of cardCheckArray; let i = index">
        <div class="card-header">
          <p>{{data}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" *ngFor = "let data2 of fetchedData">
          <div *ngIf = "data2.PROCESS_NAME == data; else printNothing">
            <p>{{data2.DOCUMENT_NAME}}</p>
            <p>{{data2.DATE_SUBMITTED | date: 'medium'}}</p>
            <p>{{data2.PROCESS_NAME}}</p>
          </div>
          <ng-template #printNothing>
            <p>empty</p>        //I am printing empty right now but it prints whitespaces if I leave it blank here
          </ng-template>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> typescript

```
var swap = this.fetchedData[0].PROCESS_NAME;

      for (var x in this.fetchedData)
      {
        if(swap == this.fetchedData[x].PROCESS_NAME)
        {
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          this.cardCheckArray.push(swap);
          swap = this.fetchedData[x].PROCESS_NAME;
        }
      }
this.cardCheckArray.push(swap);
```

How can I resolve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular still renders the `div` element with the `ngFor` directive. Since you cannot put two structural directives (`ngFor` and `ngIf`) on the same element you should use an `ng-container`. Its an element where you can place a structural directive (`ngFor` in your case), but which will not be rendered in the html. Inside that put your `div` with `card-body` class and put the `ngIf` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-container for `*ngFor` and do not use `else` and `ng-template`.

```
<ng-container "let data2 of fetchedData" >
  &lt;div class="card-body" *ngIf = "data2.PROCESS_NAME == data; else printNothing">
     …
```